# When is a lambda function better than defining?

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.x

I've seen a number of answers recently using `lambda` in the code for the answer.

I appreciate the differences between defining a function and using a lambda.

```
def add(x): 
    return x + 10

adding = lambda x:x ++ 10
```

I know that both will provide the exact same result, the lambda doesn't require to be linked to a variable either.

What I am confused about is where would it be useful to use a lambda instead of a function?

I've read documentation etc. and can appreciate the differences but in terms of situations where one is more useful than another I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: I often use `lambda` to define a quick [`key` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted): `sorted(lst, key=lambda item: item.attribute)`. Though [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) / [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) from the `operator` module could be used for these purposes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` expressions are generally used to define anonymous functions where there is no need to bind the function to a (global) name. For instance, if you just need a function to pass as the `key` argument to `sorted`:

```
sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

There are some people who think that the explicit assignment to a name for a short function looks better on one line than the implicit assignment performed by a `def` statement, but that's purely an aesthetics-based opinion with no effect on the actual code.

The biggest difference between the two is that `def` is a statement whose body can include arbitrary Python code, while `lambda` is an expression whose body must be a single expression which is implicitly returned. Given that restriction, it's usually more useful to use `def`, and many situations where `lambda` is useful are being handled by other features.

Although Python considers functions to be first-class objects, there are relatively few things you can actually *do* with them: you can call them, and store references to them. No other operations (such as composition or point-wise application—e.g., `h=f+g` meaning that `h(x) = f(x) + g(x)` for all `x`) are supported. If such operations were supported, then there would be more uses for *expressions* that create function objects.

Comment: So `lambda` on a very basic level (which my level of knowledge in python) is used almost as a time/space saving exercise. You use a `lambda` where you need a function but a `def` function just for single use would be overkill

Comment: Right. Also, by "anonymous', I really mean that it is bound to some variable (like a function argument) that will go out of scope "soon", so the memory occupied by the function object will be reclaimed. Using `def` generally binds the object to a global or otherwise long-lived name.

Comment: So it's a time and character saving alternative to defining a function when it's only single use and is more memory efficient? I think I understand it's uses now. I also now know why I've not used it because all of my functions are either complex or reused :)

Comment: Other answers have also mentioned better alternatives to `lambda`s, such as using `operator.add` instead of `lambda x,y: x+y` or `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of `lambda x: x[0]`. The general rule is that it's better to use a pre-existing function or something implemented at a lower level in the interpreter than to create a new function object.

Answer (score 1):

One situation where lambda could be preferable over using a def would be where you need to pass a one-off function as an argument, as you could put the lambda directly in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

lambdas are typically used in functional programming. In Python, lambda functions are used in conjonction with functional concepts like `map`, `reduce`, `filter` etc.

Your adding functions using `def` and `lambda` produce similar results.
Note that the lambda definition does not include a "return" statement -- it always contains an expression which is returned. Also note that you can put a lambda definition anywhere a function is expected, and you don't have to assign it to a variable at all.

In modern Python, list comprehensions replace the need for map, filter and similar functions,
and usage of lambda is kind of deprecated.

It is sometimes very useful to create a new function to call another one with some predefined arguments already set:

```
def foo(x,y):
  return x*y
```

Imagine you want to fix x to be 5, you can create a new function on the fly with
`lambda`:

```
foo_with_fixed_x = lambda y: foo(5,y)
```

But even in this case, it is preferable to rely on the `functools` module (look at `functools.partial`):

```
import functools
foo_with_fixed_x = functools.partial(foo, 5)
```

Comment: `lambda`s are generally faster than `partial` objects, though (since they create actual function objects rather than wrapped functions) and are more flexible regarding which arguments they can fix. `partial` objects avoid the late-binding problems that can bite you with `lambda` expressions, though.